# How can I find the pures states decomposition of a mixed state density matrix?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

I have to compute the concurrence of a multipartite system that is a mixture of states! First, it is required to find the pure state decomposition of the density matrix, ang That's where my problem is. 
How can I proceed?

Comment: Try the singular value decomposition.

Comment: @T.Arthur: Use the eigenvalue decomposition. However, note that the decomposition is not unique!

Answer (score 2):

Just **eigendecompose the density matrix** of the mixed state. The eigenvectors are the pure states, the eigenvalues are the associated probabilities of each state.

---

Keep in mind that the decomposition you're asking for isn't unique (whereas the eigendecomposition makes a nice unique decomposition, assuming non-degenerate eigenvalues). For example, you can decompose the maximally mixed qubit $I/2$ into:

- $\frac{1}{2} |0\rangle\langle 0| + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle\langle 1|$
- or $\frac{1}{2} |\mathbf{+}\rangle\langle \mathbf{+}| + \frac{1}{2}|\mathbf{-}\rangle\langle \mathbf{-}|$
- or $\frac{1}{3} |\mathbf{+}\rangle\langle \mathbf{+}| + \frac{1}{3}|\mathbf{-}\rangle\langle \mathbf{-}| + \frac{1}{6} |0\rangle\langle 0| + \frac{1}{6}|1\rangle\langle 1|$
- or infinitely many other things

Note: $|\mathbf{+}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$, and $|\mathbf{-}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$

Because you're allowed to find *any* decomposition, instead of just the eigendecomposition, you can do algorithmic tricks like picking random pure states, subtracting as much of that state out of the mixed state as possible (without causing negative probabilities), and iterating. Not that I recommend that particular strategy; it goes horribly slow near the end. And it's not nearly as convenient as just doing the eigendecomposition (plus you'll want the eigenvalues for other stuff, like computing the Von Neumann entropy).

Comment: As far as I can understand, the decomposition that achieves the concurrence of a mixed state is a special one. Do you mean to find/estimate this decomposition by a kind of Monte-Carlo simulation here?